# How to avoid "You tried to plan twice" at Test::More

Tags: perl, unit-testing, tdd

I'm new with unit testing.
I'm pretending to load N classes that internally uses Test::More in target to make different tests with their own encapsulation.

But I'm receveing the error: "You tried to plan twice at Tests/Bar.pm line 9."

This method of "more than one test" it's correct one, I mean it's an standard way for doing unit tests in perl? How can I get this level of encapsulation using Test::More?

Thanks in advice!

main.pl :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;


use Tests::Foo;
use Tests::Bar;

my $ret1 = Tests::Foo->run();
my $ret2 = Tests::Bar->run();
```

Tests::Foo :

```
package Tests::Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;


sub run
{
    my $ret;
    use Test::More qw(no_plan);
    my $test = Test::More->builder;
    is(1,1,'correct()');
    is(1,2,'fails()');
    return $test;#return all test object
}
1;
```

Tests::Bar

```
package Tests::Bar;
use strict;
use warnings;


sub run
{
    my $ret;
    use Test::More qw(no_plan);
    my $test = Test::More->builder;
    is(2,1,'fail()');
    is(2,2,'correct()');
    return $test;#return all test object
}
1;
```

Comment: I need to go pick up my son from nursery, but will give you a comprehensive answer upon my swift return. The short answer though is: use subtests.

Comment: OK, @amon has beaten me to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Test::More` module is built around the TAP format ([Test Anything Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol)). The first line of the test output can contain a line that declares the number of tests: `1..12`. This is useful for tools that output the fraction of successful or failed tests: `3/12 tests failed`. However, this line is optional and you can use no plan. In this case it makes sense to say when you're `done_testing`:

```
use Test::More;

is 1, "1", "stringification";

done_testing;
```

Note that `use Test::More 'no_plan'` is considered as a plan by Test::More, although it doesn't declare anything in the TAP output.

You should declare a plan (or declare that you're done) only once per process. This is not a problem, as usually testing goes like this:

1. In your project directory, you have the folders `lib/` with your modules, and `t/` with your tests. Here an example for the `Foo::Bar` module:

   ```
   ./
     lib/
       Foo/
         Bar.pm
         Bar/
           Helper.pm
     t/
       00_first_test.t
       01_second_test.t
   ```
2. A test looks like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use Test::More tests => 1;

   # some test here
   BEGIN {
     use_ok 'Foo::Bar';
   }
   ```

   That is, it preferably has a shebang and declares the number of tests. A package name is not required.
3. The tests are run with the `prove` tool which ships with Perl. Inside the directory:

   ```
   $ prove -lr t/
   ```

   The `-l` includes the `lib` directory, `-r` also looks at subfolders. You can then specify a list of tests or directories containing tests. The tests inside a directory are usually processed alphabetically, but there are options to stir that up.

   This will execute a separate process for each test. This is robust, easy to implement and to parallelize, although not terribly performant. This implies that each test is responsible for creating a fixture of it's own.

It is therefore not necessary to call your tests from a central testing script or a makefile.

If you want to execute multiple tests in the same TAP session, you can use subtests:

```
 use Test::More tests => 2;

 ok some_test;

 subtest "Nice Name" => sub {
   plan tests => 1;
   ok other_test;
 };
```

Inside the subtest, the plan is declared with the `plan` function, *not* with `use Test::More` (which would be executed at compile time, before the subtest is executed)! You could structure your test objects to be executed as subtests:

```
package Tests::Something;
use Test::More;

sub run {
  my $self = shift;
  plan tests => 2;
  ok some_test;
  ok other_test;
}
```

Then:

```
subtest "Tests::Something" => sub {
  Tests::Something->new->run;
}
```

Comment: Great answer amon, thanks very much! I used subtests for get the toy going on.